# Conditionally load router middleware Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Express JS code where I load a middleware that defines certain end-points on a router. The endpoints are specific to the user login and logout. I am adding a new authentication in which case I receive my auth token from a different service. When I receive the token from a different service I don't want those end-points to be loaded.

This is my server.js file

```
let app = express();
const authEndpoints = require('auth');  // this defines router endpoints
const alreadyAuth = require('checkHeaders'); // this middleware checks if request 
// already has the auth headers and set res.locals.alreadyAuthenticated to true else false

app.use('/', alreadyAuth);
app.use('/',function(req, res, next) {
  if(res.locals.alreadyAuthenticated === false)
    next();
else {
   console.log('authentication already exists skipping authEndpoints loading');
   next('route');
   }
}, authEndpoints); // login, logout

//continue here
app.use('/',nextMiddleware);
```

auth.js file

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  // some code
  res.sendFile('login.html');
}
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  // some code
});

module.exports = router;
```

I see the console log that prints 'authentication already exists skipping authEndpoints loading' but the endpoints /login and /logout are still accessible.

Also when I comment the whole section

```
app.use('/',function(req, res, next) {
  if(res.locals.alreadyAuthenticated === false)
    next();
else {
   console.log('authentication already exists skipping authEndpoints loading');
   next('route');
   }
}, authEndpoints); // login, logout
```

then the endpoints are not loaded.

Can someone please clarify If this not the way next('route') should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better if you use the middleware "alreadyAuth" for every request, no matter the route:

```
app.use(alreadyAuth);
```

In this way you check the headers in every request for every route. In the "checkHeaders" middleware, you must use an if statement that redirect the user to the login page if is not authenticated, and use next() in the case that is already authenticated.

```
let checkHeaders = function(req, res, next) {
    //some code that check headers
    if(isAuthenticate === false) {
        res.redirect("/login");
    } else {
        next();
    };
}
```

Now, all the end points after this middleware are not accessible if the user is not authenticated. So you can use a logout endpoint, or whatever.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello GuilloteL,
When the user is authenticated through external service our application is loaded in a container and we don't need to have the login and logout routes at all. The other service manages login and logout for us. Thus, if the authentication is already completed I don't want those routes to be accessible at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, try adding a isAuthenticated (whatever is your equivalent to this) check to the /login and /logout routes code you listed. if it's authenticated, do a redirect to the protected page, else return the user the login form (or logout thing..). :)